# can we handle exception in snowflake "sql" udf

Tags: exception, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm migrating javascript udf to sql udf in snowflake. In javascript udf there is try catch block to handle exception. How can I implement the same in SQL udf.

Comment: Hi - have you read the documentation e.g. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions.html? If you have then what is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake SQL user defined functions can’t include execution handling. The function definition needs to be a SQL expression, not a Snowflake Scripting block.

> The function definition can be **a SQL expression** that returns either a scalar (i.e. single) value or, if defined as a table function, a set of rows.

Your choices are to code the UDF to avoid triggering any error condition that you wanted to trap (e.g. with a CASE to avoid all “troublesome” input values) or use a JavaScript UDF for any place where exception handling can’t be avoided.

P.S. post a new question with your actual code if you want help on if your use case can be implemented in a SQL UDF